# Como añadir a mi base de datos un campo del formulario

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Tengo creado un formulario para añadir los campos a un base de datos, pero no consigo que el DNI que está en un select se envíe, no sé que tengo mal, pienso que es a la hora de la variable `clienteid`, pero no sé como solucionar el fallo.
Ese sería mi formulario.

```php
     <?php

    session_start();
    
    if ($_SESSION['rol'] != 1 AND $_SESSION['rol'] != 2){
        header("location: ./");
    }
    include "../conexion.php";
    
    if(!empty($_POST)) {
        $campos = [
            'dni',
            'nombre',
            'telefono',
            'direccion',
            'localidad',
            'provincia',
            'pais',
            // 'nfacturac',
            // 'nomcomponente'
            'cantidad',
            'precio',
            // 'iva',
            'totalfactura',
        ];
        $alert = '';
        foreach ($campos as $campo) {
            if (empty($_POST[$campo])) {
                $alert = '<p class="msg_error">LOS CAMPOS SON OBLIGATORIOS, POR FAVOR RELLÉNELOS</p>';
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!empty($alert)) {
            echo $alert;
        } else {
            // campos comunes
            foreach ($campos as $campo) {
                ${$campo} = $_POST[$campo];
            }
            // otros campos
            $pagada             = $_POST['pagada'];
            $nombrecomponente   = $_POST['nombrecomponente'];
            $dni                = $_POST['dni'];
            $usuario            = $_SESSION['idusuario'];
    
            $insertardatos = mysqli_query($conection, "INSERT INTO facturacliente(dni, nombre, telefono, direccion, localidad, provincia, pais, cantidad, precio, totalfactura, pagada, usuario) VALUES('$dni', '$nombre', '$telefono','$direccion','$localidad','$provincia','$pais','$cantidad','$precio','$totalfactura','$pagada', '$usuario')");
    
            if ($insertardatos) {
                // insertamos los componentes
                $num_Factura = mysqli_insert_id($conection);//devuelve el ID generado por una query (normalmente INSERT) en una tabla con una columna que tenga el atributo AUTO_INCREMENT. Si no se enviaron declaraciones INSERT o UPDATE a través de esta conexión, o si la tabla modificada no tiene una columna con el atributo AUTO_INCREMENT, esta función devolverá cero.
                $cliente_id = $_POST['clienteid'];
    
                foreach($nombrecomponente as $codigo_componente) {
                    $insertarcomponentes = mysqli_query($conection, "INSERT INTO facturaComponente(numfactura, codigo_componente, clienteid) VALUES('$num_Factura', '$codigo_componente', '$cliente_id')");
                }
                $alert = '<p class="msg_save">LOS DATOS SE REGISTRARON</p>';
                echo $alert;
            }else{
                $alert = '<p class="msg_error">ERROR AL CREAR EL COMPONENTE</p>';
                echo $alert;
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conection);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <?php include "includes/scripts.php"; ?>
        <title>Nueva Factura</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>
        <section id="container">
            <div class="title_page">
                <h1>Nueva Factura</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="datos_cliente">
                <div class="action_cliente">
                    <h4>Datos del Cliente</h4>
                    <a href="registro_cliente.php" class="btn-new btn_new_cliente">Nuevo Cliente</a>
                </div>
                <form action="" method="POST" name="form_new_cliente_venta" id="form_new_cliente_venta" class="datos">
                    <!--<div class="wd100">
                        <label>DNI</label>
                        <input type="text" name="dni" id="dni">
    
                    </div>-->
                     <div class="wd30">
                        <label>DNI</label>
                        <?php
                        include("../conexion.php");
                        $dni = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT idcliente,dni FROM cliente");
                        mysqli_close($conection);
                        $resultadorol = mysqli_num_rows($dni);//para ver cuantas filas nos devuelve
    
                    ?>
                    <select name="dni" id="dni"  >
                        <?php
                            if($resultadorol > 0 ) {
                                while ($fila_dni = mysqli_fetch_array($dni)) {
                        ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $fila_dni["idcliente"]; ?>"><?php echo $fila_dni["dni"] ?></option>
                        <?php
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wd30">
                        <label>Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required>
                        <!--Está desactivado-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="wd30">
                        <label>Teléfono</label>
                        <input type="number" name="telefono" id="telefono"  required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wd100">
                        <label>Dirección</label>
                        <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" class="dir_cliente" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wd100">
                        <label>Localidad</label>
                        <input type="text" name="localidad" id="localidad" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wd100">
                        <label>Provincia</label>
                        <input type="text" name="provincia" id="provincia" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wd100">
                        <label>País</label>
                        <input type="text" name="pais" id="pais" required>
                    </div>
                    <!--<div class="wd100">
                        <label>Numero de Factura</label>
                        <input type="number" name="num_cliente" id="num_cliente" required>
                    </div>-->
                    <!--
                    <div class="wd100">
                        <label>Componente</label>
                        <input type="text" name="nomcomponente" id="nomcomponente" required>
                    </div>
                    -->
                    <div class="wd100">
                        <label>Nombre Componente</label>
                        <?php
                        include("../conexion.php");
                        $descripcion = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT * FROM componentes");
                        mysqli_close($conection);
                        $resultadorol = mysqli_num_rows($descripcion);//para ver cuantas filas nos devuelve
    
                    ?>
                    <select name="nombrecomponente[]" id="nombrecomponente" multiple >
                        <?php
                            if($resultadorol > 0 ) {
                                while ($nombrecomponente = mysqli_fetch_array($descripcion)) {
                        ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $nombrecomponente["codcomponente"]; ?>"><?php echo $nombrecomponente["descripcion"] ?></option>
                        <?php
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wd100">
                        <label>Cantidad</label>
                        <input type="text" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wd100">
                        <label>Precio</label>
                        <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" required>
                    </div>
                    <!--<div class="wd100">
                        <label>IVA</label>
                        <input type="text" name="iva_cliente" id="iva_cliente" required>
                    </div>-->
                    <div class="wd100">
                        <label>Precio Total</label>
                        <input type="text" name="totalfactura" id="totalfactura" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wd100">
                        <label>PAGADA</label>
                        <input type="text" name="pagada" id="pagada" required>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn_save">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="datos_venta">
                <h4>Datos Factura</h4>
                <div class="datos">
                    <div class="wd50">
                        <label>Vendedor</label>
                        <p>Manuel Márquez Barragán</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wd50">
                        <label>Acciones</label>
                        <div id="acciones_venta">
                            <a href="lista_factura.php" class="btn_ok textcenter" id="btn_anular_venta">Anular</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </section>
        <?php include "includes/footer.php" ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

El error que me da cuando intento enviar el formulario es:

> ```
> Warning: Undefined array key "clienteid" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecomerce\sistema\nuevafactura.php on line 50
> ```

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a
> child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tfg`.`facturacomponente`,
> CONSTRAINT `facturacomponente_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`clienteid`)
> REFERENCES `cliente` (`idcliente`)) in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ecomerce\sistema\nuevafactura.php:53 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ecomerce\sistema\nuevafactura.php(53):
> mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO fac...') #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ecomerce\sistema\nuevafactura.php on line 53

La línea 50 corresponde con:

```
$cliente_id = $_POST['clienteid'];
```

La línea 53 corresponde con la consulta, el principal error está al insertar $cliente_id que me da fallo, si lo quito iría pero necesito relacionar ese campo:

```php
$insertarcomponentes = mysqli_query($conection, "INSERT INTO facturaComponente(numfactura, codigo_componente, clienteid) VALUES('$num_Factura', '$codigo_componente', '$cliente_id')");
```

ACLARACIÓN: el campo clienteid es una llave foránea de la tabla cliente.

Comment: Pero ahi dice que no lo estas mandando.. no lo encuentra en el post...

Comment: Manuel, en realidad le llamas `dni` porque visualmente para el usuario es lo que ve. Pero el `<select name="clienteid" id="clienteid"  >` debería ser `<select name="dni" id="dni"  >`, porque los valores que metes ahí son los del `idcliente` en la línea `<option value="<?php echo $fila_dni["idcliente"]; ?>">`. En realidad el usuario de la página elige un DNI porque es lo que ve, pero tú estás enviando el idcliente

Comment: Te recomiendo pasar la query a una variable, para hacer un echo de ella y saber que envía, también puedes usar ``$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysqli_error($conn));``, para saber que error te arroja.

Comment: También puedes usar Ctrl+Shift+I para ver lo registros del navegador, desde ahí puedes ver cuales datos se están enviando.

Comment: Como recomendación nunca generes código de esa forma, siempre separalo, no combines **html, css, php, js  etc**, en un mismo escript, dificulta demasiado la lectura y encontrar los errores.